# Output JSON with multiple arrays inside

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to output the query to JSON format with multiple arrays, but couldn't make it works correctly. I ran into this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814217/create-nested-json-arrays-using-for-json-path), but it is not quite the output I wanted.

Here are the sample tables:

```
DECLARE @Persons AS TABLE
(
    person_id int primary key,
    person_name varchar(20)
)

DECLARE @Pets AS TABLE
(
    pet_owner int, -- in real tables, this would be a foreign key to Person.person_id
    pet_id int  primary key,
    pet_name varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Persons (person_id, person_name) VALUES
(2, 'Jack'),
(3, 'Jill')

INSERT INTO @Pets (pet_owner, pet_id, pet_name) VALUES
(2, 4, 'Bug'),
(2, 5, 'Feature'),
(3, 6, 'Fiend')
```

The JSON output that I want to produce this like this below:

```
[{
    "2" : [{
            "pet_id" : 4,
            "name" : "Bug",
            },
            {
            "pet_id" : 5,
            "name" : "Feature",
            }
        ],
    "3" : [{
            "pet_id" : 6,
            "name" : "Fiend",
            }
        ]
}]
```

If regular built-in `FOR JSON Path` option is not feasible, I also take any tricks like concatenation, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can generate JSON output with variable key names using only `FOR JSON AUTO` / `FOR JSON PATH`.

For SQL Server 2016+ one possible solution is to use `FOR JSON AUTO` and `FOR XML PATH`.

For SQL Server 2017+, you may use only JSON functions to generate the expected output, starting from JSON array, containing one empty JSON object as first item. With [JSON_MODIFY()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and `lax` mode by default, the JSON output generated from `FOR JSON AUTO` is inserted as value for the key, specified by `CONCAT('$[0]."', person_id, '"')` expresssion (using expression as value for the `path` parameter is supported from SQL Server 2017). To be honest, `JSON_QUERY()` is not needed here, but as a rule, `JSON_MODIFY()` escapes all special characters in the new value. In this case you need to get a properly formatted JSON using `FOR JSON`, `JSON_QUERY()` or `JSON_MODIFY()` (`JSON_QUERY(person_json, '$')` returns the whole JSON).

Tables:

```
DECLARE @Persons AS TABLE (
    person_id int primary key,
    person_name varchar(20)
)
DECLARE @Pets AS TABLE (
   pet_owner int, -- in real tables, this would be a foreign key to Person.person_id
   pet_id int  primary key,
   pet_name varchar(10)
)
INSERT INTO @Persons 
   (person_id, person_name) 
VALUES
   (2, 'Jack'),
   (3, 'Jill')
INSERT INTO @Pets 
   (pet_owner, pet_id, pet_name) 
VALUES
   (2, 4, 'Bug'),
   (2, 5, 'Feature'),
   (3, 6, 'Fiend')
```

Statement (SQL Server 2016+):

```
SELECT CONCAT(
   '[{',
   STUFF((
      SELECT CONCAT(',"', person_id, '":', person_json)
      FROM @Persons p
      CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT pet_id, pet_name AS name
         FROM @Pets
         WHERE pet_owner = p.person_id
         FOR JSON AUTO
      ) j (person_json)
      FOR XML PATH('') 
      ), 1, 1, ''),
  '}]'
  )
```

Statement (SQL Server 2017+):

```
DECLARE @json varchar(max) = '[{}]'

SELECT @json = JSON_MODIFY(
                  @json, 
                  CONCAT('$[0]."', person_id, '"'), 
                  --JSON_QUERY(person_json, '$')
                  person_json    
               )
FROM @Persons p
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT pet_id, pet_name AS name
   FROM @Pets
   WHERE pet_owner = p.person_id
   FOR JSON AUTO
) j (person_json)

SELECT @json
```

Result:

```
[{"2":[{"pet_id":4,"name":"Bug"},{"pet_id":5,"name":"Feature"}],"3":[{"pet_id":6,"name":"Fiend"}]}]
```

Comment: It works.  Thank you so much.  If you don't mind, can you please explain the 2nd solution where you have `JSON_MODIFY`, `JSON_QUERY`. What is the `$` means?

Comment: I am still learning and really appreciated your time explaining.  Thanks again!

Comment: last question.  At the end of Cross Apply statement, it has the derived table named `j (person_json)`.  I understand the `j` which I normally used for Cross Apply, but have never seen ` (person_json)' 2nd part.  Are you stored it in a variable to use later in the JSON_Modify?

Comment: @Milacay `person_json` is a column alias for the column in `j` derived table.