# SQL to JSON - Grouping Results into JSON Array combine columns

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, generate

In SQL Server I have a table with columns (a, b, c, name1, address1, phonenumber1, name2, address2, phonenumber2). I want to  generate JSON for a row like:

```
{
   "a" : value_column_a,
   "b" : value_column_b,
   "c" : value_column_c,
   "contacts": [
{
  "name" : name1,
  "phone_num": phonenumber1,
   "address": address1
},
{
  "name" : name2,
  "phone_num": phonenumber2,
   "address": address2
}

   ]
}
```

Please, help me! I took some hours, but I could not solved it.

Comment: maybe this will be a good start https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814217/create-nested-json-arrays-using-for-json-path

Answer (score 2):

Embedding arrays of objects into JSON on Microsoft SQL Server is achieved by using [`json_query()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql) over a subquery of the nested data, such as the following...

```sql
/*
 * Data setup...
 */
create table dbo.Thingiebob (
  [a] varchar(14),
  [b] varchar(14),
  [c] varchar(14),
  [name1] varchar(14),
  [address1] varchar(14),
  [phonenumber1] varchar(14),
  [name2] varchar(14),
  [address2] varchar(14),
  [phonenumber2] varchar(14)
);

insert dbo.Thingiebob ([a], [b], [c], [name1], [address1], [phonenumber1], [name2], [address2], [phonenumber2])
values
  ('value_column_a', 'value_column_b', 'value_column_c', 'name1', 'address1', 'phonenumber1', 'name2', 'address2', 'phonenumber2');
/*
 * Example query...
 */
select
  [a],
  [b],
  [c],
  json_query((
    select *
    from (
      select name1, phonenumber1, address1
      union
      select name2, phonenumber2, address2
    ) unions ([name], [phone_num], [address])
    for json path
  ), '$') as [contacts]
from dbo.Thingiebob
for json path;
```

Which yields the following output...

```json
[
    {
        "a": "value_column_a",
        "b": "value_column_b",
        "c": "value_column_c",
        "contacts": [
            {
                "name": "name1",
                "phone_num": "phonenumber1",
                "address": "address1"
            },
            {
                "name": "name2",
                "phone_num": "phonenumber2",
                "address": "address2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```